# Error in Zoho CRM Deluge Script on searching record

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I am getting an error, when trying to execute Deluge script under workflow, when writing a function for Account module, where I need to fetch records based on filter criteria. I run below query script, but its showing the error.

```
response=zoho.crm.searchRecords("Accounts", "(Account Name|starts with|A*)");  
info response;
```

Error response:

```
{"code":"INVALID_QUERY","details":{},"message":"invalid query formed","status":"error"}
```

This query is the default query provided by Zoho blog itself. I just copied and pasted it.
Right now I am using trial Zoho account. May it be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below script as you have the search function written in API V1, which is depreciated since February 2018. Refer to the link:  https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/script/crm-search-records-v2.html

```
response=zoho.crm.searchRecords("Accounts", "(Account_Name:starts_with:A*)");
info response;
```